# WPF <class> does not exist in namespace "clr-namespace"

Tags: wpf, xaml, namespaces, aliases

I have a long running WPF application and suddenly, the XAML designer (and error list) has started to complain that certain classes cannot be found in namespace aliases.

For example, all Converters are stored in MyNameSpace.Converters, however, whenever a form is opened that contains references to converters within this namespace, the designer reports Markup errors and the project build also mirrors these errors. But these converters **ARE** within this namespace - the converters haven't changed in yonks :  the project runs fine and these converters are themselves, working fine - it would be pretty obvious if they weren't. It's at design and build stages that these errors are reported :Why would the project run if there were build errors?

I've tried cleaning the project, closing VS, restarting PC but no luck.

An example error message:

```
The name 'FPriorityBrushConverter' does not exist in the namespace 'clr-namespace:PracticonCASMgr.Converters'
```

XAML :

```
   xmlns:converters="clr-namespace:PracticonCASMgr.Converters"

...

  <Grid.Resources>
     <converters:FPriorityBrushConverter  x:Key="FPriorityBrush"/>

...
```

Opening the converters source .cs

```
namespace PracticonCASMgr.Converters

 public class FPriorityBrushConverter : IValueConverter
    {...
```

If I make a change to the behaviour of one of these converters (which return a colour btw) so that a brush of, say BLUE was returned, all the areas that use this converter do appear in BLUE - so the converter is working fine. Yet the designer persists in complaining of Markup errors.

Looking for solutions, I've found that other people have encountered this only to find that closing VS, restarting, cleaning, clicking fingers three times solves the problem but none of this has worked for me.

Totally confused and hope someone can shed some light on this.

Thanks

p.s. at the time of writing a colleague has just told me that the project now complains that a user control referenced in the XAML cannot now be found : but the project runs fine despite build errors and the user control (that has apparently disappeared) functions correctly.

Visual Studio 2012 fully updated.
Project running on network share - I say this because other people have resolved this problem by running the project locally,  but for me this is not an option.

Answer (score 4):

I just fought this battle. Along side it I had a "Design View not available for X64 and AMD targets" issue whenever this popped up even though design view is fine when I remove the references to the custom attatched properties that I created.

I found a link online saying that switching from x64 to x86 target and then back does the trick. Surprisingly that worked.

Comment: I had tried this a while ago, but did not work. I've found the ONLY solution for me was to move the project to a local drive. Since doing this I have not experienced the issue once.

Comment: Holy Frick - I've been battling this all morning! Your post, Abdunnoer was the solution. Pretty quirky behaviour Visual Studio (2012 Ultimate)!

Answer (score 1):

If you are using some kind dependency injection in your project then VS will not understand where certain resources are coming from, if they're defined in an assembly that doesn't have  a direct reference in the consuming project.

I see this all the time (I use Prism) and, as you've found, the resources are resolved OK at runtime.

Comment: Thanks for this, but all source is contained within the one assembly - there are NO external projects. And this has only started happening and is getting worse. But why, with build errors, does the project work and the areas that contain the supposed errors, function perfectly?

Comment: Ah well, worth a try. So when you say build errors, do you need you do a 'Rebuild all' and the build fails? Or just that when viewing that code the 'Error List' window shows errors? I get the latter with Prism, but those 'errors' aren't actually errors that stop a build succeeding. Sorry I can't be more help.

Comment: Yes, the Error List shows errors but the app still builds which seems  a contradiction. It means that the XAML designer is out of action. It's almost an infection - more and more forms are complaining of the same problem.

Comment: I ended moving the project to a different network folder. Since some assemblies had their relative paths altered, these had to be removed and re-added to the project. Now everything works hunkey-dory.